# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I am making an app in which i am providing Preferences to user, here i have given a option namely, **About Floogoo App**.

Now i want whenever user will click on **About Floogoo App** option, need to redirect to WebURL like : www.floogoo.com

Now i want whenever user will click on About Floogoo App > It call OpenURL class

and In Manifest.xml i have given PreferenceWindow class

Getting error like: **Unfortunately App has stopped**

*Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.contacts.PreferenceWindow}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.contacts.TimePickerPreferences*

ScreenShot has taken using this for test:

```
  <com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.contacts.TimePickerPreference
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:key="about"
    android:summary="Summar"
    android:title="About App" />
```

Comment: which android api you are using,and what is the target emulator version you are running

Comment: no such method error will come if you use the target api in lower android versions

Comment: @koti so what you recommend me, what target api i should use..?

Comment: you have to call the method if your device supports target api.otherwise you have to call alternative method .

Comment: what is the method your calling at GenericInflater.java:377

Comment: 1) Where do you start TimePickerPreferences? 2) I don't see TimePickerPreferences in your manifest. 3) What's in line 25 of the layout xml?

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong 1)In Preferences.xml 2) <activity android:name="com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.contacts.PreferenceWindow"/> 3)<com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.contacts.TimePickerPreferences   need help

Comment: @Harpreet not solved..need help

Answer (score 0):

Change your code.

```
Intent browserIntent = 
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

with

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

and let me know.